# Video lagging issue with opencv and dlib

Tags: python, opencv, flask, dlib

I am a newbie and currently I am working on Video processing. I am using  Imutil's webcamvideostream function to capture the live stream and dlib's get_frontal_face_detector() function's object as detector.I am detecting the facial landmark using the dlib library. After detection and fetching the facial features, I am processing each frame before yielding it. 
This all runs fine for few seconds but after a min or two, the video starts lagging and it gradually increases with the time.

I have tried to minimize the processing time by running process in threads. Also I reduced the frame rate and resolution. I have also tried skipping frames but that is not resulting in smooth video.
I placed timeout on the detection function when exceeds the average minimum time(this is the only function which is taking more time in execution).
Reducing frame rate and resolution did reduced the lagging but if the video keeps running for 5 min, lagging starts again.

How can I resolve this lagging issue and get a smooth video for long time?

Here is a structure that might help.

```
def frame_pro(form_data=None):

### Making a webcam object by WebcamVideoStream and detector by get_frontal_face_detector()

while True:
    frame = camera.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)

    ### Processing each frame

    ### yielding all frames in response after encoding

    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
            b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n' + stringData + b'\r\n')

del camera
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


@app.route('/callp', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def callp():
    if request.method in ['POST']:
        all_data = request.form.to_dict()
        return Response(frame_pro(all_data), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    else:
        return Response(frame_pro(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I was finally able to resolve the issue. The issue was with the flask and not the opencv or dlib. As I was trying to do it in run time, I had to change the way flask was handling my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this topic [Working with hundred thousand of pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563169/dlib-cv2-working-with-hundred-thousand-of-pictures/53739843#53739843) to reduce the processing time of dlib.

However, your lagging problem starts happening after some "smooth" minutes (you said after 5 mins), I have a doubt about memory consumption management. For example, after each iteration, there is an array that gets bigger and never be released. You should post your code with comments here so we could suggest further.

Comment: Hello Peter,I did checked and yes, it is causing because of resource crunch which raises my next question.I am calling an API endpoint which is processing my frames and yielding it back. Now each time I am submitting the form, it is creating a new process for that while the last process still exist (because the API is never returning and always yielding).So after a while the video starts lagging.Is there any possibility to handle this situation where I can do this in runtime and also take care of my previous processes?

Comment: I also tried killing the previous processes generating on each request after a minute, but terminated my API call (main process).